# Qt::How to identify/detect if the system is Remotely access by other system in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, remote-access

I am developing an application in ubuntu to access the other system remotely through QT. Both system are running some Qt applications.I want to check / make changes to the other system remotely using Qt programming.

I want to add a **pushbutton** (as a quit screen) at remote system that should be **"Enable only if the system is remotely accessed"**, so that i can use it to close the remote access screen.

Is there any way through programming we can get the status whenvever it is remotely accessed???

I got through some solutions on forum but they are particularly for Windows. **I am looking for some solution in Linux.**

Please provide suggestion/links so that i can overcome this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Define more precisely what "access remotely thru Qt" means to you. Also, say more about the Windows specific solution you thought about.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Using Qt I am able to login to the Remote screen  Display using "VNCViewer" in QProcess.
While Window Specific means using windows library function to get the system status.There are many solutions for windows.
But I am looking for a solution in Linux.

Comment: Then the remote access is not from your application, but from the `VNCViewer` program. And you could use the `netstat` thing mentioned in my answer.

Comment: or programmatically dive into `/proc/net/` .... So read about `proc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the remote display abilities of the [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) protocol, you could check the value of the `DISPLAY` variable. For a local connection, it usually starts with `:0`; for a distant connection, it contains the hostname of the displaying server. For a connection thru `ssh -X` it could be `localhost:10` and `ssh` is also setting `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variables.

Otherwise, you should define better what is a remote access for you (i.e. explain more your application). Your Qt application may also be e.g. some TCP/IP server. Perhaps the [getpeername(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpeername.2.html) syscall might be relevant.

If you just are interested in what remote connections flow into your box (independently of a particular application) you could read (e.g. using `popen`) the output of command `netstat -a -n` or use some `/proc/net/` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using netstat. It gives a list of ports listening/connection established. Is there any way to filter out the Established Connection/ check the particular port. 
From programming point of view its very inconvenient for us list.

Comment: Also When the system is remotely accessed, it creates an ICon on the top Panel. So i think , there must be a inbuilt Linux library function (just like window) to get the status of the Screen when remotely accessed.

Comment: @skg Come on now, this is linux! `netstat -a -n | grep ESTABLISHED` is a start.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple, thanks for your answer. This is one of the best way to do it. But still i think there is more ways to achieve this pro-grammatically.
Will surely update over here if i find some better way.